# Convert char* into String

Tags: c++, string, char, esp8266, sming

I am using ESP8266 Wifi chip with the SMING framework which uses C++. I have a tcpServer function which receives data from a TCP port. I would like to convert the incoming `char *data` into String data type. This is what I did.

```
bool tcpServerClientReceive(TcpClient& client, char *data, int size)
{
    String rx_data;
    rx_data = String(data);
    Serial.printf("rx_data=%s\r",rx_data);
}
```

The contents of `rx_data` is rubbish. What is wrong with the code? How to make `rx_data` into a proper string?

Comment: Maybe '\0' is missing at the end of data : try data[size] = '\0'

Comment: The way you are printing it seems like rubbish. Try `Serial.printf("rx_data=%s\r",(const char*)rx_data);`

Comment: @StoryTeller, nothing wrong with `Serial.printf`. If rx_data is a proper string, it will print out fine.

Comment: May I ask why the negative vote? What is wrong with the question? Can someone explain so that I can improve on the question?

Comment: If `Serial.printf` is a variable argument function, and `String` a proper class, than the code as written has [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432539/c-passing-classes-to-vararg-function). There is a very limited set of things that can be legally passed as var-args. The only way to make it well defined is to use a proper cast to a type that *can* be passed to a varargs function.

Comment: @user1824987 : If you give some examples it should be better. Also, you can use a debugger to see what you have inside data and why rx_data is rubbish

Comment: @user1824987 You say "If rx_data is a proper string". What does that  mean? What is the definition of `String`? Is it something defined by sming?

Comment: user2079303, the String data type used in SMING is same as the one used in Arduino. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/string

Comment: Well, [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) page pretty much tells us that you invoke undefined behavior. It may work, or fail gloriously until the parameter is something the `printf` can accept. Besides, even if it works for some long strings, the small string optimization will certainly mess it up for small strings.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but it's a waste of time to create a `String` object with the default constructor then create a temporary to assign to it. Just create it with the argument: `String rx_data(data);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why what you are doing is *wrong*:

A C style string is an array of `char` where the last element is a `0` Byte. This is how functions now where the string ends. They scan the next character until they find this zero byte. A [C++ string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is a class which can hold additional data.

For instance to get the length of a string one might choose to store the length of the stirng in a member of the class and update it everytime the string is modified. While this means additional work if the string is modified it makes the call t length trivial and fast, since it simply returns the stored value.

For C Strings on the other hand length has to loop over the array and count the number of characters until it finds the null byte. thus the runime of `strlen` depends on the lengh of the string.

### The solution:

As pointed out above you have to print it correctly, try either:

```
#include <iostream>
...
std::cout << "rx_data=" << rx_data << std::endl;
```

or if you insist on printf (why use c++ then?) you can use either [`string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str), or (since C++11, before the reutrned array might not be null terminated) [`string::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data): your code would become:

```
Serial.printf("rx_data=%s\r",rx_data.c_str());
```

I would suggest you have a look at [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to get an idea of the details. In fact if you have the time a good book could help explaining a lot of important concepts, including containers, like `std::string` or `std::vector`. Don't assume that because you know C you know how to write C++.